# WPF: How to get character coordinates in TextBlock?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, custom-controls

I have TextBlock that I am customizing in code without XAML. One thing I need to do now is to get coordinates for certain character that are contained in TextBlock (eg. get Rect for that character relative to the TextBlock top left corner). How can I go about doing this task? I guess I need to implement some custom method such as

```cs
Rect TextBlock.GetRectForCharacter(int charIndex);
```

Is there a way I can accomplish this? Note that TextBlock can also be multi-lined.

Comment: ran into similar issue before, the best solution I can come up with is do some calculation base on the font size and number of characters

Comment: Could you please provide some code example to get me start and help me out?

Comment: As far as I know `GetRectForCharacter` only available for `TextBox`. But you can create a `TextBox` and "make it" as `TextBlock` using style and parameter `IsReadOnly="True"`.